# Viewing multiple kibana dashboards in one place

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I have multiple instances of Kibana for different servers, I would like to be able to see one page that summarize/displays all of the dashboards, is that something that is achievable through a separate website? I was thinking of having one website that displays each and individual dashboard as iframe

Multiple instances of kibana and elasticsearch

I expect one single website

Answer (score 1):

Iframes are possible, but I'm not sure this is really what anybody wants.

The more elegant solution would be [cross cluster search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cross-cluster-search.html) where you can connect to multiple clusters and combine data from them in a dashboard. You could structure that any way you want. Just be careful with the [supported version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-remote-clusters.html#gateway-nodes-selection), since I see the tag *kibana-4*, which is really old by now.

Comment: Thanks mate, you see the problem is that i cannot cluster those elasticsearch instances, as they are in separate AWS accounts so they dont have the visibility of each other

Comment: Is that the AWS managed service or are you just using EC2 instances? With EC2 instances it's definitely possible — you'd just need to set up the right network permissions.

Comment: It's not the AWS Managed Services unfortunately, but deliberately separated VPCs across multiple accounts. I want to be able to see one single dashboard for each Kibana in that accounts. I have one VPC that is peered into those multiple VPCs so thats way there is a one single point from which i can access it.